# New front fork on old Cannondale XR800

Tags: fork

I have an old 2000 Cannondale XR800 (CAAD3?) that I want to upgrade with a non-suspension, disk-brake compatible front fork. Something like [this](http://www.nashbar.com/bikes/Product_10053_10052_175019_-1___).

But what fork to buy? Anything I should know about standards, measurements etc?

I believe I may be capable of putting everything (fork, wheel, disk, caliper) together. But I know nothing about fork/stem standards and compatibility and such.

--

The bike currently has the original Rock Shock fork with suspension in/at the steering stem. It's been great, but I really really want disk brakes and the suspension doesn't really give me much (I think :) plus it needs maintenance all the time.

I am considering buying a new bike altogether, but I like this old bike. And I have a feeling this old frame can keep up with modern ones. Feel free to correct me on this.

Comment: Is it really an XR800? That seems like a cross bike, which wouldn't have a suspension fork. I wouldn't bother with this plan though. Selling the old bike and getting a newer (probably used) bike already with disc brakes would be more cost effective and probably result in a better bike. Major upgrades like this practically never pay off, unless you can do them for very cheaply and you have a deep desire for wanting the upgrade.

Comment: Batman is right, the XR800 didn't have suspension. Either you have some other model, or the previous owner switched the fork. Pictures would help.

Comment: Sorry, it's a XS800, a sibling of the XR800 i believe, but with suspension. Typo. My bad. I've googlet some more and it seems the stem diameter is kinda strange on this frame/fork? So I guess replacing the fork is a challenge.